# Как через бота выдать пользователю роль discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать команду для выдачи роли через бота в подобном плане, то есть просто и незамудренно и без классов, чтобы я понял, потому что я новичок:

```
@bot.command()
async def giverole(ctx):
    ctx.author.give_role(ID роли)
```

**Не обязательно подобный пример, нужен просто короткий и синтаксически простой для понимания работы. Можно без пояснений, я по названиям методов сам сориентируюсь что да как в ответе.**

Дальше я разберусь сам, мне простого примера достаточно, для хорошего понимния конструкции
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хорошо, я тебе скину без объяснений, но если вопросы появятся, обязательно пиши!

```py
@bot.command()
async def giverole(ctx):
    role_id = 1234567890  # Замени на ID нужной роли
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(role_id)
    
    if role:
        await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f"Роль {role.name} успешно выдана!")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Указанной роли не существует. Пожалуйста, укажите корректный ID роли.")
```

Comment: Спасибо, я понял.

Comment: А можно как-то роль забрать?

Comment: в смысле? @MCSasha